# Can't get s3 object from IAM admin role, 403 error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have set an S3 object, test.json in my S3 bucket, 'MyBucket', I have an IAM role which belongs to a group that has AdministratorAccess role.

I want to be ablt to read that test.json, using accessKeyId and secretAccessKey.

This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

@Injectable()
export class AwsService {

  constructor() {
    AWS.config.update({
      region: 'us-east-1',
      credentials: {
        "accessKeyId": "myaccessKeyId",
        "secretAccessKey": "mySecretAccessKey",
      }
    });
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
    console.log(s3,'s3');
    let params = {
      Bucket: 'myBucketName',
      Key: 'test.json'
    };
    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack, 'fail'); // an error occurred
      else console.log(data, 'success');           // successful response
    });
  }
}
```

However, I get 403 error.

My thought is if I am using the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey that belongs to an admin user, I should be able to retrieve that object.

However, this is the console output:
[image]

**Even I change the accessKeyId and the secretAccessKey, the output is the same, it's SUCCESS! This also happens when I change it to a wrong value on purpose.**

This is my Bucket:
[image]

This is CORS config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

try wihout the credentials object:

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  accessKeyId: "myaccessKeyId",
  secretAccessKey: "mySecretAccessKey",
});
```

Comment: try changing the file to allow all access... and try to access the file in the browser... just to be sure the file exists... the bucket is the correct one, etc

Comment: yes, If I change it to allow everyone read access, it works, so there is something isn't set up right in my code or console.